# how to save a file in GAP

Tags: group-theory, permutations, gap

Sorry for a simple question.
I'm trying to save a file in GAP using LogTo(filename) and load using Read, but it not works.
I studied a lot from online GAP books, but could not understand.
Any easy way to save the file and reload it again?
I'm using window 8.1Pro.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: `LogTo` will not save. There is `SaveWorkspace`, but that might be complicated to use under Windows.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what the problem is. It would be helpful to describe in more detail what does not work and let us know which parts of the documentation are unclear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**LogTo(filename)** will just print everything that you see in your terminal to a file (including output and errors), so you won't be able to read it in.

If you want to store your input to read in later, try **InputLogTo(filename)** instead.

For example, try:

```
LogInputTo("test");
G := SymmetricGroup(5);
g := Random(G);
```

Now quit GAP, restart it, and type

```
Read("test");
```

You should find that it works fine, and moreover, the variables $G$ and $g$ are set as they were in the original instance.

Note: You can also replace "test" with any filename, and also a file path if you like.

[See the manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap9.html) for more info!

Comment: I studied the manual but didn't catch my problem.
Can we give any name instead of the filename? Like InputLogTo(XYZ).
I will be grateful if you explain a little more.

Comment: I added an example to my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Melissium Sir, I tried so many times, but the above commands are not working.

Comment: Could you give some description of the error?

Comment: There is no error occurs. But when I save the file with InputLogTo(“filename”); quit; then restart again and give Read(“filename”); this could not return the program.

Comment: It runs the commands automatically for you. If you're actually looking for the text file where it's stored, you will have to look in the directory where GAP is installed, or use a filepath the write your input to a different directory.

Comment: As documentation of `InputLogTo` says it changes handling of the subsequent input, not those lines that you have entered already. I suggest to look at https://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#5.4 and also https://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/03-func/.

Comment: Now got it. Thank you for your valuable answers and links.

Comment: You're welcome! Also, for Windows, a good editor for GAP code is Notepad++ which also has a syntax highlighting for GAP which you need to install as explained  at https://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#8.3

Comment: @ChockaBlock: Two comments: In answer, you have written **LogInputTo**. Second comment: what does out we get by the command **Read("test");**?